# php + upload.class + not overwriting the image

Tags: php, upload, overwrite

i am trying to upload a file with upload.class and i need to overwrite the file when the user upload a new one. But instead of overwriting, he is putting photo_01, photo_02, etc... 
The code:

```
        $foto = new Upload($_FILES['photo']);
        $fotot = new Upload($_FILES['photo']);
        $fotot->image_resize = true;
        $fotot->image_y = 110;
        $fotot->image_x = 110;

        $foto->file_new_name_body = "photo";
        $fotot->file_new_name_body = "photo";
        $foto->file_overwrite = true;
        $fotot->file_overwrite = true;
        $fotot->Process("{$dir_fotos}thumbs/");
        $foto->Process("{$dir_fotos}");
```

Somebody has already passed by this or has a solution??? notice that i'm using `file_ovewrite = true;`
thanks

I solved the problem...sorry spending your time

Comment: This is a custom class, nobody is going to be able to give more information about this without some more code. But could it be that you are just spelling `code_overwrite` wrong? There's an `r` missing.

Answer (score 0):

As per the faq, there is no need to instantiate the class twice for same file. U just create one instant and then call process twice.
refer official faq page - http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_faq.htm